# How do I call a function using a function name generated from a string variable

Tags: php

In the process of automating some code, I am looking to call upon a function based on what a string is.

For example, I have a variable `$somevar` which is set to the string "This".  Now I want to run a function `doThis();`

So, I was hoping I could write `do.$somevar($var,$var2)` .  I want it to run `doThis($var1,$var2)`.

Is this possible?

Comment: are the range of possibilities for $somevar known and limited or unknown and unlimited?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [call_user_func](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) to accomplish this.

```
call_user_func("do" . $somevar, $var1, $var2);
```

You can also use [is_callable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-callable.php) to check for error conditions.

```
if (is_callable("do" . $somevar)) {
    call_user_func("do" . $somevar, $var1, $var2);
} else {
    echo "Function do" . $somevar . " doesn't exist.";
}
```

Comment: As far as i know call_user_func works on any callable function, even built in php functions like strtoupper, sprintf, ...

Comment: @ChrisRamakers  You're right, thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do it like that, but you could do:

```
call_user_func('do'. $somevar, $var, $var2);
```

or

```
$func = 'do' . $somevar;
$func($var, $var2);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly legal in php

```
$myVar = 'This';

$method = 'do'.$myVar; // = doThis
$class  = new MyClass();
$class->$method($var1, $var2, ...); // executes MyClass->doThis();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$fname="do$somevar";
$fname();
```

But you should think twice before using it.

Answer (score 0):

In php you use -> instead of .
this will work:

```
$foo = new someObject;
$somevar = 'function_name';
$foo->$somevar('x');
```

Comment: I think Roeland was using the . as the string concatenation operator

Answer (score 0):

check [call_user_func](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) or call_user_func_array

```
class myclass {
    static function say_hello()
    {
        echo "Hello!\n";
    }
}

$classname = "myclass";

call_user_func(array($classname, 'say_hello'));
call_user_func($classname .'::say_hello'); // As of 5.2.3
```